# Writing Out The Number of Zeros From 1 - 1,000,000

Tags: combinatorics

If you had to write out all the numbers between 1 and 1,000,000. How many zeros would you have to write in total.

I was given that the answer is 488,895. Can any one show the clearest way possible of getting this figure. The couple ways I have tried have given me an answer that is about half of that figure.

Comment: And what exactly have you tried?

Comment: Hint:  Count the number of zeros in al 1-digit numbers; then all 2-digit numbers; then ...

Comment: 6+9*654321-5400000= 488895. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 6 positions where the zeros can occur.  They will occur in that position 1 out of 10 times.  Or at total of $\frac {1,000,000}{10} = 100,000$ times.  So there should be a total of $6*100,000 = 600,000$ zeros.

Except zeros do not appear in tens position if the number only has one digit.  So that removes $9$ of the potential zeros.  That is, we *would* have counted $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ as $01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09$ but we don't write those zeros so there are only $600,000 - 9$.

Likewise if the number is less then $100$ we don't count the first zeros in the $100$ position.  We count $27$ and $27$ not $027$.  So none of the zeros from $1$ to $99$ aren't counted.  Sothere are only $600,000 - 9-99$.

We do that for the zeros in 4,5, and position.  So there are $600,000 - 9 -99-999- 9,999 - 99,999$ zeros.

$9+99+999+9,999 + 99,999  = 10 -1 + 100 - 1 + 1000 - 1 + 10,000 - 1 + 100,000 -1 = 111,110 - 5$ so there are $600,000 - 9 -99-999- 9,999 - 99,999= 600,000 - 111,110 + 5 = 4,888,895$ zeros.

Answer (score 3):

*Claim*: For $k \geq 2$, the number of zero digits among $k$-digit numbers is $(k-1)(10^{k-1}-10^{k-2})$.

> *Proof*: There are exactly $10^k$ sequences of $k$ digits, and in this collection there are $k\cdot 10^k$ digits in total, and each digit occurs the same number of times, i.e., $k \cdot 10^{k-1}$ times.
>   From these, we exclude those that have a $0$ at the start.  There are exactly $10^{k-1}$ sequences of $k$ digits that start with $0$.  Ignoring the starting zero, each digit occurs the same number of times, i.e., $(k-1) \cdot 10^{k-2}$ times.
>  This gives $k \cdot 10^{k-1}-10^{k-1}-(k-1) \cdot 10^{k-2}$ zeroes.

So, the answer is $$6+\sum_{k=2}^6 (k-1)(10^{k-1}-10^{k-2})=488895.$$

This can be verified computationally using the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
count:=0;
for i in [1..1000000] do
  for d in DigitsNumber(i,10) do
    if(IntChar(d)=48) then count:=count+1; fi;
  od;
od;
count;
```

which returns `488895`.

Answer (score 1):

How may zeroes appear from 1 to 1000000?

10% of 10,00,000 = 1,00,000

No of 1 digit numbers ×1 = 9×1 = 9

No of 2 digit numbers ×2 = 90×2 =180

No of 3 digit numbers ×3 = 900×3 = 2,700

No of 4 digit numbers ×4 = 9,000×4 = 36,000

No of 5 digit numbers ×5 = 90,000×5 = 4,50,000

No of 6 digit numbers from 1 to 1,00,000×6 = 1×6 = 6

Sum of (9+180+2,700+36,000+4,50,000+6) = 4,88,895 zeroes

Sum of each digit from 1 to  (10% of 10,00,000) = 4,88,895 zeroes.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! You're off to a good start. One suggestion is to add LaTex. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to note that there are 600,000 of each of 1-9 from 000,000 to 999,999, a total of 5,400,000.

Now, the number of digits of all numbers from 1-999,999 is:

$1 \times 9 + 2 \times 90 + \cdots +6 \times 900000 = 9\times 654321 = 5,888,889$.

Therefore the number of zeros is 6 + 5,888,889-5,400,000 = 488,895.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fresh way to solve this problem:

How many $1$-digits are there?  largest - smallest + 1:  or 9 - 1 + 1 = 9.

What is the total number of digits contributed by $1$-digit numbers?  $1 \cdot 9 = 9$

How many $2$-digit numbers are there?  $99 - 10 + 1 = 82$

What is the total number of digits contributed by $2$-digit numbers?  $2 \cdot 82 = 164$

How many $i$-digit numbers are there?  $10^{i-1} - 10^i$.

So how many digits are contributed in the $i$-digit numbers?

$i (10^{i-1} - 10^i)$.

How many total digits are contributed by all $6$-digit numbers (i.e., up to 999,999)?

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^6 i (10^i - 10^{i-1}) = 5,888,889$.

How many digits are contributed up to $1,000,000$?  We merely add the seven digits of $1,000,000$, thus:  $5,888,896$.

Each of the nine digits $1, \ldots, 9$ appear 600,000 times in that list, except $1$ which appears one more (from its appearance in $1,000,000$).

The remaining digits must be $0$s:

$\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^6 i \left(10^i-10^{i-1}\right)+7\right)-9 \cdot 600000-1 = 488,895$.

Verified by *Mathematica*:

```
Counts[Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ Range[{1, 1000000}]]]
```

(* 
<|1 -> 600002, 2 -> 600000, 3 -> 600000, 4 -> 600000, 5 -> 600000, 
 6 -> 600000, 7 -> 600000, 8 -> 600000, 9 -> 600000, 0 -> 488895|>
*)